# Casting into jsonb creates \ inside my jsonb

Tags: json, postgresql, jsonb

So I have the following problem. We normally store json values in normal text fields in our database. Postgres Database

Normally i use this insert into skript

```
    insert into public.my_table
(records)
select records::text
        from (  select 
        '{"cus_test":{' ||
        string_agg('"' || 1 || code || '":{"code":"' || 1 || code || '","de":"' || bez || '","fr":"' || bez || '","it":"' || bez || '","en":"' || bez || '","cd":"' || 1 || '","code":"' || code || '"}', ',') || '}}' as records
        
    from (select '01' as code, 'Test 1' as bez
union all select '02', 'Test 2'
union all select '03', 'Test 3'
union all select '04', 'Test 4'
)d
cross join (select '1' as mandant   
                 )m     
                    
                    )daten
```

Now we changed the datatype to jsonb and so i made following changes to the script

```
insert into public.my_table
(records)
select records::jsonb
        from (  select 
        to_jsonb('{"cus_test":{' ||
        string_agg('"' || 1 || code || '":{"code":"' || 1 || code || '","de":"' || bez || '","fr":"' || bez || '","it":"' || bez || '","en":"' || bez || '","cd":"' || 1 || '","code":"' || code || '"}', ',') || '}}') as records
        
    from (select '01' as code, 'Test 1' as bez
union all select '02', 'Test 2'
union all select '03', 'Test 3'
union all select '04', 'Test 4'
)d
cross join (select '1' as mandant   
                 )m     
                    
                    )daten
```

Now the datatype is jsonb but i have everywhere \ inside my jsonb...

Output

```
"{\"cus_test\":{\"101\":{\"code\":\"101\",\"de\":\"Test 1\",\"fr\":\"Test 1\",\"it\":\"Test 1\",\"en\":\"Test 1\",\"cd\":\"1\",\"code\":\"01\"},\"102\":{\"code\":\"102\",\"de\":\"Test 2\",\"fr\":\"Test 2\",\"it\":\"Test 2\",\"en\":\"Test 2\",\"cd\":\"1\",\"code\":\"02\"},\"103\":{\"code\":\"103\",\"de\":\"Test 3\",\"fr\":\"Test 3\",\"it\":\"Test 3\",\"en\":\"Test 3\",\"cd\":\"1\",\"code\":\"03\"},\"104\":{\"code\":\"104\",\"de\":\"Test 4\",\"fr\":\"Test 4\",\"it\":\"Test 4\",\"en\":\"Test 4\",\"cd\":\"1\",\"code\":\"04\"}}}"
```

Where does this come from and how can i clean it?

UPDATE 2:

So I tried as @a_horse_with_no_name said to build this with jsonb_build_object() but now i get 4 rows instead of 1

```
        select records::jsonb
        from (select 
        jsonb_build_object('cus_test',jsonb_build_object(mandant || code,jsonb_build_object('code',mandant || code,'bezeichnung_de',bez_de,'bezeichnung_fr',bez_fr,'bezeichnung_it',bez_it,'bezeichnung_en',bez_en,'cus_immopac_mandant_cd',mandant,'cus_immopaccode',code))) as records
from (select '01' as code, 'Pruefung 1' as bez_de, 'Test 1' as bez_fr,'la proova 1' as bez_it,'Test 1' as bez_en
union all select '02','Pruefung 2','Test 2','la proova 2','Test 2'
union all select '03','Pruefung 3','Test 3','la proova 3','Test 3'
union all select '04','Pruefung 4','Test 3','la proova 4','Test 4'
)d
cross join (select '1' as mandant
                 )m     
                    
                    )daten
```

Row 1

```
{
  "cus_test": {
    "101": {
      "code": "101",
      "bezeichnung_de": "Pruefung 1",
      "bezeichnung_en": "Test 1",
      "bezeichnung_fr": "Test 1",
      "bezeichnung_it": "la proova 1",
      "cus_immopaccode": "01",
      "cus_immopac_mandant_cd": "1"
    }
  }
}
```

Row 2

```
{
  "cus_test": {
    "102": {
      "code": "102",
      "bezeichnung_de": "Pruefung 2",
      "bezeichnung_en": "Test 2",
      "bezeichnung_fr": "Test 2",
      "bezeichnung_it": "la proova 2",
      "cus_immopaccode": "02",
      "cus_immopac_mandant_cd": "1"
    }
  }
}
```

This should all be in 1 row as before

Comment: Use `jsonb_build_object()` or `jsonb_object_agg()` rather than concatenating strings

Comment: well since i never used that before and the work with concatinating the string already is done i was thinking i could save some time and just cast the text -> jsonb.

Comment: @user2210516 It seems like the double quote escaping is done by your client. Although it could use some improvement and cleanup, your insert should work fine exactly as it is. [Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/OnCLD57Q). You can see PostgreSQL doesn't see a problem casting this to jsonb and using the resulting jsonb in functions that take it as input, nor does it add an escape backslash when cast back to text.

Comment: In your attempt to follow @a_horse_with_no_name's advice you just need to swap your second `jsonb_build_object()` for a `jsonb_object_agg()`. [Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/qT1Bg57B).

Answer (score 0):

Nested JSON result are better assembled in stages.

```
with data (code, bez) as (
  values 
    ('01', 'Test 1'),
    ('02', 'Test 2'),
    ('03', 'Test 3'),
    ('04', 'Test 4')
), languages (lang) as (
  values ('de'), ('fr'), ('it'), ('en')
)
select jsonb_build_object('cus_test', jsonb_object_agg('1'||code, l))
from (
  select code, 
         jsonb_object_agg('bezeichnung_'||lang, bez) || 
             jsonb_build_object('code', '1'||code) || 
             jsonb_build_object('cus_immopaccode', code) || 
             jsonb_build_object('cus_immopac_mandant_cd', 1) as l
  from data
    cross join languages
  group by data.code
) x
;
```

The innermost query returns this result:

```
code | l                                                                                                                                                                                    
-----+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
01   | {"code": "101", "bezeichnung_de": "Test 1", "bezeichnung_en": "Test 1", "bezeichnung_fr": "Test 1", "bezeichnung_it": "Test 1", "cus_immopaccode": "01", "cus_immopac_mandant_cd": 1}
02   | {"code": "102", "bezeichnung_de": "Test 2", "bezeichnung_en": "Test 2", "bezeichnung_fr": "Test 2", "bezeichnung_it": "Test 2", "cus_immopaccode": "02", "cus_immopac_mandant_cd": 1}
03   | {"code": "103", "bezeichnung_de": "Test 3", "bezeichnung_en": "Test 3", "bezeichnung_fr": "Test 3", "bezeichnung_it": "Test 3", "cus_immopaccode": "03", "cus_immopac_mandant_cd": 1}
04   | {"code": "104", "bezeichnung_de": "Test 4", "bezeichnung_en": "Test 4", "bezeichnung_fr": "Test 4", "bezeichnung_it": "Test 4", "cus_immopaccode": "04", "cus_immopac_mandant_cd": 1}
```

The outer query then uses `jsonb_object_agg()` to combine these rows into a single JSON value. adding the constant keys (code, cus_immopaccode, cus_immopac_mandant_cd) could also be done on the outer level. I just thought the outer `jsonb_object_agg()` looks a bit cleaner then.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now it's for all 4 languages the same value "Test 1". How can i solve the problem if the bez is different for each language? bezeichnung_de = pruefung 1, bezeichnung_it = la proova 1 and so on..

Comment: Obviously, because the sample/demo data doesn't contain that and you haven't shown how you would match those test values to the real language.

Comment: your correct. It wasn't in my demo since we normally just put 1 language in all of the fields. Now when im correcting the code i was thinking about adding all languages. I edited my demo with different values for each language

Comment: @user2210516 Please avoid edits that change the question or expand it beyond original scope. Improvements suggested by @a_horse_with_no_name deserve a separate thread. Alternatively, you can re-title to focus on proper json construction, and edit to rephrase the question accordingly, only mentioning the backslash issue as a side-problem. Keep in mind this thread is supposed to be searchable and relevant to the people searching for the same problem in the future. The answer to your original question here about `\ ` is that it's likely just added by your client, which should be configurable.